# Parsing get_video_info in android

Tags: android

I want to parse the get_video_info file in android. It's not like a HTML or XML file, so how to parse it to get data??

Sample file: http://pastie.org/8396979

Comment: i want to parse it....not decode it :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code to get key-value pairs in an Hashtable:

```
String[] lArgs = responseString.split("&");
Hashtable<String,String>keyValues = new Hashtable<String, String>();
for (int j = 0; j < lArgs.length; j++) 
{
    String[] keyValuePairs = lArgs[j].split("=");
    if (keyValuePairs != null) {
    if (keyValuePairs.length >= 2) {
        keyValues.put(keyValuePairs[0], URLDecoder.decode(keyValuePairs[1], "UTF-8"));
                               }
                    }
}
```